# JMeter and Sitescope Monitors - Is it possible to pass metrics to SiteScope so an application can be monitored in real time?

Tags: jmeter, monitoring, sitescope

We are setting up SiteScope application monitoring and are currently using out of the box standard port, URL and Service types of monitoring.

However, for some applications there is a requirement to know the application response time for certain user actions. The only option that is available, and currently working, are a series of 6 JMeter scripts which are part of the current performance test suite.

Is it possible to monitor the JMeter response times via SiteScope monitoring. Unfortunately, and why my problem arises,  is that no changes can be made to the application, and no additional software packages can be installed, so ideally it needs to be pure JMeter > SiteScope solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a [Custom Monitor](https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/SiteScope:2020.10/CreateCustomMonitors) configured to read data from

- either JMeter [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) - [Custom Log File Monitor](https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/SiteScope:2021.05/CustomLogFileMonitor)
- or from [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) (JMeter can be [configured to send its metrics to InfluxDB using Backend Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)) - [Custom Database Monitor](https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/SiteScope:2021.05/CustomDatabaseMonitor)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for that.

It is as I thought then, at least from the JMeter perspective, acting as a supplier of data for use by a Custom Monitor for Sitescope  

The InfluxDB route is not an option, so it is going ti have to be a non standard, custom solution then. Not what others may wish to hear, but at least options are available.

Comment: After further research, the solution proved incredibly simple.

1. JMeter writes the .jtl in XML/CSV format as required by the SiteScope Monitor which polls the file for the required response time entries being written.
2. Create a file share for writing the .jtl to from JMeter, then grant read permissions to the share from SiteScope.